# Set representing The positive integers which are a multiple of 6?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I know this is a very trivial question, but I'm probably missing something

So the set is:

$\{n\mid n=2m\, \mathrm{for \,some} \,m \in \Bbb N,\mathrm{and}\,n=3k\, \,\mathrm{for \,some}\, k \in \Bbb N\}$

How come this set is: The positive integers which are a multiple of $ 6$?

Comment: Have you heard about the fundamental theorem of arithmetic?

Answer (score 1):

$n=2m$ and $3\mid n$ means $3\mid 2m$. Since $3\nmid2,3$ must divide $m$, or $m=3p$. Thus, $n=6p$.

Answer (score 0):

$n=2m$ means that $2$ divides n. $n=3k$ and $n=2m$ simultaneously imply that $3$ divides $2m$ but $3$ can't divide $2$ which means that $3$ will divide the l.c.m of $2$ and $3$ which is $6$. So $n=6h$ where $h$ belongs to $N$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Thanks I will make sure about it.